# Connect PC 4k 60FPS to TV over range

Tags: pc, desktop, television

I am about to move into my new appartment and I have to following problem:

I will have my desktop pc in my office room and would like to connect my 4k TV (LG, 2018 model) to my pc for some gaming on the couch (4k appreciated, 1440p and 60 FPS required).

However, I do not know what the best (and reasonably cheap) solution would be. I do have an existing connection via Ethernet cable and also have the possibility to get another wire through the existing cable tubes in the wall. The range would be approximately 20 meters, coming through a electrical box after 5-7 meters.

I would need both a solution for video/audio, with HDMI on the tv side, pc is either HDMI2.0b or DP1.4 (got an RTX 2080), but also how I would have to handle my input (Xbox controller, both classic wired and/or Elite 2, and a wireless keyboard with touchpad (USB dongle))

Thank you for your help.

Comment: A high quality HDMI cable would be the simplest but I am not sure they can be that long for the bandwidth you need.   If your games are on Steam, their streaming solutions might be useful for you with a suitable device attached to the tv.

Answer (score 0):

Let me just think that through step by step

### Video and audio output

There is an LTT video about running HDMI (1.4 - fullhd 120hz or 4k 30hz) over a CAT7 ethernet cable, but he has not tried it with an RTX 2080, but if you can get DP to HDbaseT and watch the video, that shoud be doable. Link to video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Kk5TTjxHwGY

(of just buy an active HDMI 2.0/2.1 cable that is long enough, but the video way is more interesting and I like tweaking)

### Keyboard and mouse input

Bluetooth 5 keyboard and mouse could be the best option here, if your pc supports it.

### XBOX controller

This could get tricky, because Bluetooth 4 doesn't have the biggest range... That depends on the place where you game and where your pc is.

Answer (score 0):

A free(!) option would be to install [Moonlight](https://github.com/mariotaku/moonlight-tv#download) on your tv. it's a bit of tinkering compared to the others but it might be worth a shot.
While I do not have access to my system right now. I'll update later today on the quality of this application.

A cheap solution would be to get an an android tv stick/box with the connectors you need. then install steam link to get to your games. Results between products can vary though since the signals need to be encoded/decoded.

Since setups like this can quickly be a disappointment due to delay between controller input and screen output. I would suggest not cheaping out and go for a more premium option. Nvidia has a device for this called the [shield](https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/shield/). From what read this is one of the lowest delay options out there compared to other remote gaming options and built specifically for the scenario you are describing.